# How to find the function caller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have build an angularjs application. there are many places I used javascript `console` functions.
now I want to use a single variable to turn off those console. 
I dont want to check the variable everytime whenever I use the console function.
so I decided to make a service to handle that process.

**Console factory**

```
AppModule
.factory("$console", function (ENV) {
    function log (txt) {
        var args = arguments;
        if(ENV.debug) {
            console.log.apply(this, args);
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
});
```

And I called that function like the following way.

**Controller**

```
AppModule
.controller('CommonCtrl', function ($scope, $console
    $scope.personalInfo = function () {
            $scope.errmsg = false;
            getPersonalInfo(function (data) {
                if(!$scope.errmsg) {
                    $console.log("userdatainfo:",data);
                }

                ...
                ...
    })
});
```

All is working perfectly. 
But Only the problem is I can only see the line number of the factory file on inspect panel.
I need to have the line number from where the factory function is getting called (like the line no of the above controller file).
Please reply with valuable suggestion.

Comment: why dont you use `console.trace()` the same way like you did with the `log`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a javascript feature and not specifically Angular. You can use arguments in a function like this. However the line number is not given but you get the caller name.

```
function Hello()
{
    console.log("caller is " + arguments.callee.caller.toString());
}
```